# test-kitchen: how to read platform specific attributes in kitchen.yml

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, test-kitchen, chefdk

In my `.kitchen.yml` config I am trying apply attributes depending on platform version. My kitchen config looks like that:

```
platforms:
  - name: centos-6.3
    driver_plugin: ec2
    driver:
      image_id: ami-xxxxxxxx
    attributes:
      pg_version: "9.3"
  - name: centos-6.5
    driver_plugin: ec2
    driver:
      image_id: ami-yyyyyyyy 
    attributes:
      pg_version: "9.4"
```

During `kitchen converge` process I am not able to get `pg_version` value correctly. For this code in my chef script `pp node.debug_value('pg_version')` output is the following:

```
   [["set_unless_enabled?", false],
    ["default", :not_present],
    ["env_default", :not_present],
    ["role_default", :not_present],
    ["force_default", :not_present],
    ["normal", "9.4"],
    ["override", :not_present],
    ["role_override", :not_present],
    ["env_override", :not_present],
    ["force_override", :not_present],
    ["automatic", :not_present]]
```

I don't clearly understand this result. I assume precedence level of the attribute I specified in `platforms` yml section is `normal`, so how can I get it?

User [danieljimenez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95363/danieljimenez) also raised similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661252/test-kitchen-store-credentials).

Comment: Can you show us how you're accessing the attribute? I'd expect it in `node['pg_version']`.

Comment: @Martin just updated

Comment: @Martin  Does it mean all platform attributes are by default at `normal` precedence level and we need to use smth like `node.normal['pg_version']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various precedence levels are merged into a single `node` object. You'll want to access it using `node['pg_version']` in your case. You only need `node.default`, `node.set`, `node.override` when setting the value.